# SQL join table on a modified key

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, dbvisualizer

I am trying to join  table on a modified key. I am getting b.buser does not exist.

```sql
SELECT 
a.name,
a.work_id,
a.email_id,
a.Legal_name,
b.username,
left(b.username,11) as buser,
b.email,
FROM a
left join b on a.work_id=b.buser
```

Comment: The parser tells you there's no column `buser` in table `b`. What is the structure of your tables and what is modified key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only believe the parser: `b.buser doesn't exist.`

Looking at your SQL, you're probably trying to reference `left(b.username,11)`, which you aliased to `buser`.  This is different than `b.buser`.

Try this one:

```
left join b on a.work_id=left(b.username,11)
```

Comment: This worked. weird i could not get the reference from the Select. Thanks!

Comment: If you had referenced ```buser``` instead of ```b.buser```, it might have worked.  I never remember when I can reuse an alias like that and when I can't, and it probably depends on the RDBMS version.

But b.buser definitely didn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason why you need `left(b.username, 11)` in the `select`.  Why is it there?  If it is non-`NULL`, it is the same as `a.work_id`:

```
SELECT a.name, a.work_id, a.email_id, a.Legal_name,
       b.username, b.email,
FROM a LEFT JOIN
     b
     ON a.work_id = LEFT(b.buser, 11)
```